# How to update mysql data with event and remove the event after

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table that looks like this

```
| begintime  | endtime  | begindate  | enddate  | state |
+------------+----------+------------+----------+-------+
|  TIME      | TIME     |    DATE    |   DATE   | string|
+------------+----------+------------+----------+-------+
```

I have this code

```
CREATE EVENT Update
ON SCHEDULE
  EVERY 1 SECOND
DO
  UPDATE tablename SET tablename.state = CASE
   WHEN (SELECT CURRENT_TIME() FROM DUAL)>=tablename.begintime AND (SELECT CURDATE()>= tablename.begindate) THEN "Available"
   WHEN (SELECT CURRENT_TIME() FROM DUAL)>tablename.endtime AND (SELECT CURDATE()= tablename.enddate) THEN "Finished" 
   ELSE "Not Available"
   END
```

I want the server to be always checking if any of those statements is true, and I dont know how to remove the event when:

```
WHEN (SELECT CURRENT_TIME() FROM DUAL)>tablename.endtime AND (SELECT CURDATE()= tablename.enddate) THEN "Finished
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try this one.

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
DROP EVENT IF EXISTS Update1;
CREATE EVENT Update1
ON SCHEDULE
  EVERY 1 SECOND
DO
  UPDATE tablename SET tablename.state = 
  CASE
   WHEN NOW() BETWEEN CONCAT(tablename.begindate,' ',tablename.begintime) AND CONCAT(tablename.enddate,' ',tablename.endtime) THEN "Available"
   WHEN NOW() > CONCAT(tablename.enddate,' ',tablename.endtime) THEN "Finished"
   ELSE "Not Available"
  END;
```

To drop the event after setting to "Finished" try using something like this

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
DROP EVENT IF EXISTS Update1;
DELIMITER //
CREATE EVENT Update1
ON SCHEDULE
  EVERY 1 SECOND
DO BEGIN
    SELECT @begindate := begindate,
           @begintime:= begintime,
           @enddate := enddate,
           @endtime := endtime FROM tablename;
    IF (NOW() BETWEEN CONCAT(@begindate,' ',@begintime) AND CONCAT(@enddate,' ',@endtime)) THEN
        UPDATE tablename SET state = 'Available'; 
    ELSEIF (NOW() < CONCAT(@begindate,' ',@begintime)) THEN
        UPDATE tablename SET state = 'Not Available';
    ELSEIF (NOW() > CONCAT(@enddate,' ',@endtime)) THEN
        UPDATE tablename SET state = 'Finished';
        DROP EVENT IF EXISTS Update1;
    END IF;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```